# Mysql virtual machine remote connection failure

Tags: mysql, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I created Virtual Machine on Virtual Box by using vagrant with puppet configurations. In vm, i can connect to mysql db however I want to connect VM's mysql from my local machine.

Firstly, I tried to change "**bind-adress**" value in **my.cnf** then restarted mysql service however it didn't work. I think i could not change bind-address as it should be. When i run "mysql --help" command bind-address's value is "No Default Value".

VM properties:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- mysql 5.6
- forwarded_port ( host:7104 -> guest:22 )

Part of the "***mysql --help***" command [image]

Part of the "***my.cnf***" is
 [image]

P.S. => After i changed /etc/mysql/my.cnf file, i restarted mysql service

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Step1: comment bind address entry in your cnf file.

step2: restart mysql service.

step3: stop iptables service if you are not using any other purpose-

```
service iptables stop
```

Step4: grant permission to one user, which will connect your db remotely.

```
grant all privileges on *.* to user1@'%' identified by 'user1';
```

Here to test I have provided all rights globally, you can prepare grant statement as per your requirement.